# How to remove files on batch extension rename

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

what I am trying to is change the file extensions from png to jpg, but on the folder there are duplicated names something like abc.jpg and abc.png and when I try to run the cm command to change extensions I can not do it because it says there is a duplicated file.

So how can I just overwrite the files when it is duplicated?

I am using "ren *.png *.jpg" on cmd to change the extension. Take notice that there are about 5000 files so go one by one is imposible.

Any help or suggestion would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a command that will allow you to overwrite the existing file.  So you can use a simple `FOR` command to list the files and then use the `MOVE` command to change the file extension and overwrite any existing files.

You can run this from the command prompt.

```
for %G IN (*.png) do move /Y "%G" "%~nG.jpg"
```

If you need to use it in a batch file then double the percent symbols.